# C# format an array for post to Api

Tags: c#, arrays, json, string, api

I am trying to get the correct format for the json array I need to pass to a post request.

The example code I got shows the following format when using c# as the preferred programming language:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.us/v2/webinars/94395753143/panelists");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer _XU6l1eaDs9NQRTcb5QG4m0-ab1F3Y29ikw");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"panelists\":[{\"name\":\"Mary\",\"email\":\"maryjkdfdsgfshdgf@jdfdkjdglfk.jkfgdj\"},{\"name\":\"Mike\",\"email\":\"dfdsgfsdhf@jkgfdgfkdhgfdjg.fkjgdf\"}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

As proof of concept, I am getting the values from an angularjs view formatting the json array, and passing them through the post request:

```
$http(request)
    .then(function successCallback(data) {
    
        angular.forEach(data.data, function (item) {
            
            var b = {
                name: item.Name,
                email: item.Email
            };
            $scope.arr.push(b);         
        });

        var parData = JSON.stringify({ 'panelists': $scope.arr, 'id': $scope.webinarId, 'bearer':  $scope.bearer});

    $http.post('/api/AddPanelists', parData)
        .then(function (data) {
    }), function (data) {
        alert("An error occurred during the request");
    };
```

In my C# code I have a function that receives parDAta and retrieves each of the 3 elements passed (array, id, bearer)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreatePanelists(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {
        Parameters parameters = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parameters>(data.ToString());

        IList<Panelist> panelists = parameters.panelists;  << this value does not seem right
        string webId = parameters.id;      << this value is fine
        string bearer = parameters.bearer; << this value is fine

        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.us/v2/webinars/" + webId + "/panelists");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", panelists, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

    }
    
    public class Panelist
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
    public class Parameters
    {
        public IList<Panelist> panelists { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public string bearer { get; set; }
    }
```

When I check the console.log in the browser, to see if JavaScript is formatting the json is correct, I see this:

```
{"panelists":[{"name":"Jack Anderson","email":"janderson@email.com"},{"name":"Ed Johnson","email":"ejohnson@email.com"},{"name":"Dead Poole","email":"dpoole@email.com"},{"name":"Hank  Schmidt","email":"hschmidt@email.com"},{"name":"Steven Alves","email":"salves@email.com"},{"name":"Nilvio Alexander","email":"nalexanderemail.com"}],"id":94395753143,"bearer":"U19hW2pkQkO2A0Zv5EXz-h4kXJ56s"}
```

When I check the value once it makes it to the C# side of things, the string looks a bit different:

When I check what has been passed, here:

```
public void CreatePanelists(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data) << here
```

The value looks:

```
{{
  "panelists": [
    {
      "name": "Jack Anderson",
      "email": "janderson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ed Johnson",
      "email": "ejohnson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dead Poole",
      "email": "dpoole@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hank  Schmidt",
      "email": "hschmidt@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steven Alves",
      "email": "salves@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nilvio Alexander",
      "email": "nalexander@email.com"
    }
  ],
  "id": 94395753143,
  "bearer": "U19hW2pkQkO2A0Zv5EXz-h4kXJ56s"
}}
```

**I see extra curly brackets at the beginning and at the end of the string.**

My goal is to be able to pass an array that looks exactly as the 3rd party api needs the array to be formatted, I do not think I am doing it correctly.

This is the format I need to have, specifically for the **panelist** string

```
{
  "panelists": [
    {
      "name": "Jack Anderson",
      "email": "janderson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ed Johnson",
      "email": "ejohnson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dead Poole",
      "email": "dpoole@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hank  Schmidt",
      "email": "hschmidt@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steven Alves",
      "email": "salves@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Nilvio Alexander",
      "email": "nalexander@email.com"
    }
  ]
 }
```

Thank you for reading my question, I hope I can get a bit of help.
If I need to clarify anything, please just let me know.

Thanks,
Erasmo

UPDATE

[image: screen shot]

I think the extra curly braces are gone, but how do I know that the string to be passed will look like this:

```
{
  "panelists": [
    {
      "name": "Jack Anderson",
      "email": "janderson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ed Johnson",
      "email": "ejohnson@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dead Poole",
      "email": "dpoole@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hank  Schmidt",
      "email": "hschmidt@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Steven Alves",
      "email": "salves@email.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alejandro Nava-Gomez",
      "email": "anava-gomez@cityofmadison.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "itortu",
      "email": "itortu@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
 }
```

If you see the screen shot, I am not sure it looks correct. May be I am looking at the output and not understanding what the actual value will be passed.

Comment: How you are checking string on c# side?

Comment: Did you try to change action parameter type to `Parameters`? 
`public void CreatePanelists(Parameters parameters)`

Comment: @Fabio - I did not try to change that part. I can give it a try, I think that when I change the type of argument, then the method does not get call from JavaScript, but let me try.

Comment: @Fabio - yeah, I tried and changed to  public void CreatePanelists(Parameters data), but then the method does not get executed. Not sure why but that is what happens.

Comment: Did you add `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter? `Create([FromBody] Parameters data)`

Comment: @Fabio - No I did not, let me try.  I will report shortly.

Comment: @Fabio - I added a screen shot of my output. How can I be sure that the array looks as I need it?

Comment: @erasmocarlos - is this question you asked a duplicate, seems like you're asking essentially the same thing with this an expanded version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706573/how-to-concatenate-to-string-correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new object to satisfy expected structure.

```
[HttpPost]
public void CreatePanelists([FromBody] Parameters parameters)
{
    var webId = parameters.id; 
    var bearer = parameters.bearer;
    var data = new
    {
        panelists = parameters.panelists
    };

    var client = 
        new RestSharp.RestClient($"https://api.us/v2/webinars/{webId}/panelists");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", $"Bearer {bearer}");

    request.AddParameter("application/json", data, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
}
```