# How to concatenate to string correctly

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have a simple and basic question.

I have this sample code:

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer _XU6l1eaDs9NQRTcb5QG4m0-ab1F3Y29ikw");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"panelists\":
[{\"name\":\"Mary\",\"email\":\"maryjkdfdsgfshdgf@jdfdkjdglfk.jkfgdj\"},
{\"name\":\"Mike\",\"email\":\"dfdsgfsdhf@jkgfdgfkdhgfdjg.fkjgdf\"}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I want to replace the hard coded values:

```
_XU6l1eaDs9NQRTcb5QG4m0-ab1F3Y29ikw
```

and

```
"{\"panelists\":
    [{\"name\":\"Mary\",\"email\":\"maryjkdfdsgfshdgf@jdfdkjdglfk.jkfgdj\"},
    {\"name\":\"Mike\",\"email\":\"dfdsgfsdhf@jkgfdgfkdhgfdjg.fkjgdf\"}]}"
```

with 2 string variables:

```
  IList<Panelist> panelists = parameters.panelists;
  string bearer = parameters.bearer;
```

I am having a brain fart and cannot get it right, what is the correct way to concatenate these variables to the string?

I am doing:

```
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
        request.AddParameter("application/json", panelists, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

But that is not working right.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: _"with 2 string variables:"_ - I only see one string variable. The other is a list of `Panelist`.

Comment: You are correct, pardon my lack of correctness. One is a variable and the other is a list of valus.

Comment: I don't understand how you intend to make a single string out of these values. Especially when one seems to be a bearer token, and the other seems to be the request body. They don't really seem like candidates to make into a single string.

Comment: Can you shed some light on what "that is not working right" means, since that could mean virtually anything?

Comment: @John, I apologize for not posting my question correctly. I guess what I need is to be able to format the list of values in a way that I can pass it as the request body, and the bearer token as the sample code with hard values does.

Comment: You are using `bearer` correctly. You need to json serialize the list to get the expected string representation. You can use NewtonSoft.Json library to perform the serialization

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - Thank you. I tried to do that, but then I get an error. Did it this way:  IList<Panelist> panelists = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameters.panelists);  buecasue one is a string and the other is an IList.

Comment: Serializing to JSON turns your list into a string. You have you assign JSON to a `string` variable, not an `IList<Panelist>`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of comments. It is still unclear what exact errors/output you are getting and how it is different from what you want. Side note: consider using `HttpClient` like everyone else so you can easily copy examples instead of coming up with own class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: OP has asked the question here** [C# format an array for post to Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62706228/c-sharp-format-an-array-for-post-to-api)

> I need to format the list of values in a way that I can pass it as the request body.

You'd need to convert the IList back to a String? Hence wouldn't it be better to represent the JSON structure with a Model:

```
public class Panelist    {
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public string email { get; set; } 

}

public class Root    {
    public List<Panelist> panelists { get; set; } 
}
```

Add the JSON to the Model *or populate the Model on initialization*:

```
myJson = {\"panelists\":
    [{\"name\":\"Mary\",\"email\":\"maryjkdfdsgfshdgf@jdfdkjdglfk.jkfgdj\"},
    {\"name\":\"Mike\",\"email\":\"dfdsgfsdhf@jkgfdgfkdhgfdjg.fkjgdf\"}]}";

Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myJson)
```

And then serialize the Model to a string:

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDeserializedClass), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```